# Binding and adding parameter in UPDATE statement: PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a parameter value to be bound in my `UPDATE` query, but it  happens that my parameter does not get assigned to the query and it does not update my result.

Here is my code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Update Person p set age= age+:gap where age>:presentAge");
query.setInteger("gap", myLogicForGap.size() + 1);
```

- `myLogicForGap` comes from a List which is passed in method
  parameter.
- Could you help me with some changes in my code or some alternative
  where `:gap` value gets added to `presentAge`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first approach would be changing age to p.age and presentAge to p.presentAge

Comment: For postgreSQL we do not need an alias. I earlier had the same code you are trying to suggest.

Comment: Try adding spaces between the placeholder and the operators. And are you also calling `query.setInteger` to set a value for `presentAge`? Is that query specific enough? It looks like it will increment a lot of ages...

Comment: I am not trying to set a value for presentAge. And i have made this query up, since i cannot share my code. I will try to add spaces as you suggested. I tried using sum(). Didnt work though.

Comment: Adding spaces didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried running a native version of that query with the same parameters. Maybe nothing matches the `where` condition (which already looks like a horrible idea if this is the only condition).

Comment: It is the code i have made on custom, the main thing that i need is adding :gap to presentAge